# KnockoutJS select fires onChange after setting default value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have set up the following select for changing semesters on page. When the select detects a change, the `changeSemesters` function is fired, which runs an AJAX that replaces the current data on the page with data specific to the selected semester.

**View**

```
<select data-bind="options: semestersArr, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: selectedSemester, event: { change: changeSemesters }"></select>
```

**ViewModel**

```
this.selectedSemester = ko.observable();

//runs on page load
var getSemesters = function() {
  var self = this, current;

  return $.get('api/semesters', function(data) {
    self.semestersArr(ko.utils.arrayMap(data.semesters, function(semester) {
      if (semester.current) current = semester.id;
      return new Model.Semester(semester);
    }));

    self.selectedSemester(current);
  });
};

var changeSemesters = function() {
  // run ajax to get new data
};
```

The problem is that the change event in the select fires the `changeSemester` function when the page loads and sets the default value. Is there a way to avoid that without the use of a button?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally what you want to do in these scenarios is to use a [manual subscription](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly-subscribing-to-observables), so that you can react to the observable changing rather than the change `event`. Observables will only notify when their value actually changes.

So, you would do:

```
this.selectedSemester.subscribe(changeSemesters, this);
```

If `selectedSemester` is still changing as a result of getting bound, then you can initialize it to the default value.

```
this.selectedSemester = ko.observable(someDefaultValue);
```

Comment: Sorry, I accepted this yesterday, but I was half asleep. I tried your second approach, but I can't really initialize the observable with the default value, because I'm waiting to get that value after the Ajax call. And if I do the init there, `subscribe` will return an error. I set up a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hqH7K/

Comment: As you can see, after the values have loaded, `selectedSemester` becomes 10 for a split second because that's the first option value in the select. Is there a way to make the select ignore the initialization process and fire on user select? Using a button would solve the issue, but I'm trying to build the selection without having to use one.

Comment: @Norbert - can you clarify your issue from the fiddle? It looks like it is undefined until your options come back.

Comment: Yes, but the value becomes 10 after the options come back, instead of waiting for `selectedSemester` to finish being set to the default value, which is 20. I wanted it to jump from undefined to 20 so that the subscribe on line 7 only fires once on page load. I also went to the KnockoutJS Google Group and I was told to use the new `valueAllowUnset` binding in the 3.1 beta, which solved the issue. Here's a fiddle of it should work: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/hqH7K/1/ – Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you are okay using 3.1 beta, so `valueAllowUnset` is a great option for this issue.